# Vertical shift of margin citations in tuftebook

Tags: citing, tufte-book

I'm typesetting a large book in `tuftebook` and use `\cite{}` for citations, which appear in the margins (and bibliography).  Because of multiple citations, `\marginfigure{}`, and so on, such margin citations and figure captions often overlap or are crammed together.

How can I manually shift the location of a margin citation while preserving the location of its associated source superscript numeral in the text body?

Comment: I think that a MWE would help this question.

Comment: Good luck with your book project, by the way.